# What is causing the yellowing on my English Ivy's leaves?

Tags: indoors, containers, potting-soil, english-ivy

Same unfortunate newbie from [this thread](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/wilting-coleus-plants)

I have some ivy plants that two weeks after transplant are yellowing of the leaves and starting to look rather sad.  These were purchased as full size plants that were being grown indoors in the nursery, so not much change in light was transitioned to my home.

I'm wondering if perhaps I might be overwatering them?  Would a stint outside help?  Is this something I should worry about?

[image]

[image]

Comment: English Ivy does do better out of doors, if you have protection from direct afternoon sun in summer.

Answer (score 2):

The compost I can see in the pot in the top picture looks pretty dry, and having gone back to your Coleus question, one of the pictures shows a pot with dampish compost in the middle, but a dry portion over to one side.

Is it possible you're just not watering enough? That certainly looks to be the problem with your ivy - freshly repotted plants should be thoroughly watered, so that the water runs out of the bottom and all the compost is wet, and any excess in an outer tray poured away so they're not standing in water. After that, its a thorough soaking when the surface of the compost feels a bit dry to the touch, but not shrunken from the sides of the pot. 
I'm not sure whether that's one ivy plant in the pot or more than one, so have they got enough root room? Ivy is fine with sun so long as its roots aren't bone dry, but it's also fine in total shade, it's one of the most unfussy plants available.

Otherwise, could there be a problem with the potting medium you have used?